# Proper way to free GPU memory when using directX?

Tags: memory, directx

I've been working through a handful of directX tutorials. They all mention           `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx`

for loading an image from a file into video memory. However, nobody (that I've seen), talks about how to free up that memory. Can I just call free() on the pointer that is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like almost all of the DirectX API, when you create a new object, it's returned as a pointer to a COM interface. In your case you get a pointer to an [`IDirect3DTexture9`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.

When you want to release these resources, you use the normal COM method for disposing of reference-counted interfaces, by calling `Release()` on the pointer:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pTexture = NULL;
D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx( /* ... */, &pTexture);

// ... use the texture .....

// release interface
pTexture->Release();
pexture = NULL;
```